# Is increased blood flow always correlated with increased cerebral activity?

Tags: brain, blood-circulation, medical-imaging

I've heard that cerebral fMRI (Functional magnetic resonance imaging) maps blood flow through the brain, and it is **most of the time** correlated with cerebral activity. What are the factors that can mess with this correlation and when does this happen?